# I cant set my content type to the correct format

Tags: angular, typescript, http, visual-studio-code

I am trying to send the formdata to authenticate my user. But i have the wrong content type. It needs to be x-www-form-urlencoded but it currently used multipart/form-data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class SecurityInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private _router: Router) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
                // url: `http://localhost:5000/${request.url}`,
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
                    Content-Type: 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
            // next.handle(request);
        }
        if (token == null || token == "") {
            this._router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this._router.navigate(['login']);
                }
                return throwError(err);
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with this: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: Ill lle tyou know if it worked

Comment: It doesnt work @robert

Comment: Can you share the login form part?